# Slicer refreshing data

Tags: odbc, powerbi

I have 6 tables (measurement and targeted as a pair) appliances targeted and measured, electronics targeted and measured, household targeted and measured, that are connected in powerBI using ODBC. I have made three tables using merge table as new (Household, electronics, appliances). Now i have shown the data in tabular form and bar graph using appliances. And I have created a slicer with three custom options Appliances, household and electronics. Now I want this slicer to change the appliances data in the graph and table to change to household and electronics depending upon the selection made in the slicer.

Kindly help me out, I have changed the names as the data is highly confidential. Let me know if I didn't provide much clarity.

thanks a bunch

Comment: Could you give a bit more info about the model? How many tables are there left, and how are they connected (relationships)? It sounds like you use the slicer on a field which is not connencted to the 'data table'. But it's hard to say, could you post a screenshot of the model view?

Comment: The tables are connected based on one primary key, but that is done on the backend in phpmyadmin designer. Yes the values in slicer are not connected but I don't know how to so, couldn't do it. Also I'm not aware how to share screenshot, let me try to edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a slicer to work how you want, I think the easiest approach would be to merge all your tables into a bigger one with product type as a new column.

For example, if tables `Household`, `Electronics`, and `Appliances`,

```
ID   Name    Value
------------------
101  Chair   80
102  Desk    120

ID   Name    Value
------------------
203  Phone   800
206  Tablet  650

ID   Name    Value
------------------
311  Washer  380
367  Dryer   440
```

would become

```
ID   Type         Name    Value
-------------------------------
101  Household    Chair   80
102  Household    Desk    120
203  Electronics  Phone   800
206  Electronics  Tablet  650
311  Appliances   Washer  380
367  Appliances   Dryer   440
```

Then you'd add a slicer on `Type`.

Comment: nice solution but in actuality there are about 100-1000 row per table, it will be difficult to create a value for each. I was hoping to do it a simpler like in sql you could just add the column to the table while loading the table EX: LOAD 'HOUSEHOLD' AS 'TYPE', Name as Name; SQL SELECT * FROM Household; but I'm unable to find the same in powerBI.

Comment: You can definitely create a custom column in the query editor. Add Column > Custom Column > Use `Type` as column name and `"Household"` as the formula (include quotes).